# If $ a\le b+c $ then $ a^q \le C(b^q + c^q) $?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ and $q>1$. If
$$
a\le b+c
$$
then
$$
a^q \le C(b^q + c^q)
$$
holds for some constant $C>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g \colon (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x) = x^q$. Notice that $g$ is a convex function for $q > 1$, indeed $g''(x) = q(q - 1)x^{q - 2}$ which is positive.

This gives $$\Big(\frac{b + c}{2}\Big)^q = g\Big(\frac{b + c}{2}\Big) \le \frac{g(b) + g(c)}{2} = \frac{b^q + c^q}{2}.$$

Then $$a^q \le (b + c)^q \le 2^{q - 1}(b^q + c^q).$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a = 1, b = c = 1/2$. Then as $q \to \infty$, we have that your left hand side is always $1$, while the right hand side goes to $0$ (very, very, very quickly) for any $C$.

So there is no $C$ so that $a^q \leq C(b^q + c^q)$ based on the restrictions $a,b,c > 0, q > 1$. $\diamondsuit$

More broadly, for general $a$, if we let $b = c = a/2$, then we can see that no general $C$ should exist. By expanding $a$ as a binomial expansion, and noting that in this case every power $b^j c^{q-j}$ are the same, then this amounts to asking how large the binomial coefficients $q \choose k$ can get. And they can get arbitrarily large. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: perhaps $C = C(q)$?

Comment: @Giovanni that's an interesting thought. Yes, then it would work. And it would be a power of $2$, as choosing the halfway point is distinguished by symmetry. Such considerations were not clear to me from the OP. (edit) Ah, and now I see you've provided exactly that answer.

Comment: At least now the combination of our answers is sure to satisfy any future reader :)